# insert IPA into MySQL

Tags: mysql

I wish to save the IPA phonetic pronunciation against a word in a simple dictionary. I have a simple table where the IPA field is collated to UTF8_GENERAL_CI. I have a script that is running to extract the IPA from a source and write that into the table.

If I show the SQL prior to execution, the command looks fine. If I retrieve what IPA value after save, it is garbage. If I look at it using PHPMyAdmin, it is garbage. If I overwrite the value using PHPMyAdmin edit then it shows perfectly via PHPMyAdmin

```
UPDATE vocab_word SET phonetic='[ˈaːχənɐ]' WHERE id=4
```

What I see when retrieving it is '[ËˆaËÏ‡É™nÉ]' and this is what I see within PHPMyAdmin.

So, I know I am getting it in the format I want, I know that if it is saved correctly, PHPMyAdmin can show it, but something is happening during the write to convert it.

I have tried :-
VARCHAR with UTF8_General_ci collation
VARCHAR with UTF8_bin
TEXT with UTF8_general_ci
TEXT with UTF8_bin

Within the SQL, I have tried simply using the value (as above) as well as using a UTF8_encode.

I am assuming there is a specific combination that I need to save the IPA text of encoding in the SQL and the database, and will continue to try combinations, however if someone can save me some time, I would really apprecaited it.

Regards
Chris H

Comment: What Unicode pane do those chars belong to? MySQL's `utf8` is actually not real UTF-8, just a subset. You need `utf8_mb4` to use characters that use 4 bytes. (Collation doesn't matter: a wrong one will only make `ORDER BY` and `=` less reliable.)

Comment: Oh, now I realise I forgot the most basic question: do *other* UTF-8 characters actually work?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a combination of things....
I needed to convert the character_set for the database to utf8mb4
I needed to convert the character_set for the table to utf8mb4
Collations needed to also be utf8mb4
plus the mysql connection needed to have it's character_set set.

Any one of these not done caused the characters to be mutated.